# Change Dispform.aspx in search results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I would like to change the Dispform.aspx to something more meaningful, but not sure how to do this

See Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to solve this is to make sure a **Title** property is available and filled in for each item in your list, that's what the Search page uses by default.

Otherwise you can **modify the item display template**, that will allow you to customize the display of search result snippet. There is a great article here on that process.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/08/27/understanding-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/