# How to customize search results in list page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience, sharepoint-search

I'm using SharePoint Online modern experience.
When I use OOTB search in my list, the results is just Dispform.aspx.aspx.

[image]

How to customize this search result?
I would appreciate any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution**

Quick way to solve this is to make sure a **Title** property is available and filled in for each item in your list, that's what the Search page uses by default.

Otherwise you can **modify the item display template**, that will allow you to customize the display of search result snippet. There is a great article here on that process.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/08/27/understanding-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/

> Source: [Change Dispform.aspx in search results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89933/change-dispform-aspx-in-search-results/89940)

**Second solution**

You can also set crawl rule for search query to **show only files**:

`{?{searchTerms} IsDocument:"True"}`

> Source: [Using crawl rules to exclude Allitems.aspx, DispForm.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100985/using-crawl-rules-to-exclude-allitems-aspx-dispform-aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. But is your Second solution working also Modern experience? I cannot find that search results edit page.

Comment: Did not try. According to the source it supports only `shp-enterprise` and `shp 2013`

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, you cannot customize the modern search in SharePoint Online.

The modern search text box is visible on the top header of the SharePoint. Microsoft search can be managed through Microsoft 365 admin center, but the **admin cannot customize the modern search experience UI**.

Generally speaking, click on the modern search text box will display 4~5 list items.

[image]

**Please perform the following troubleshooting:**

1.Does the list have multiple items with the same title/name?

2.It may be that items have not been search crawled, so these items cannot appear in the search box. It is recommended that you wait for a while (up to 24 hours)